# Combined sign in and registration page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is somewhat against rails convention but I am trying to have one controller that manages both user session authentication and user registration. I am having troubles figuring out how to go about this.

So far I am merging the User Controller and the Sessions Controller and having the 'new' method deliver both a new usersession and a new user instance.

With the new routes in rails 3 though, I am having trouble figuring out how to generate forms for these items.

Below is the code:

## user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    @user = User.new
  end
  
  def create_user
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Account Successfully Registered"
      redirect_back_or_default signup_path
    else
      render :action => new
    end
  end
  
  def create_session
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default login_path
    else
      render :action => new
    end
  end
  
end
```

## views/user/new.html.erb

```
<div id="login_section">
    <% form_for @user_session do |f| -%>
        <%= f.label :email_address, "Email Address" %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.label :password, "Password" %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>
        <%= f.submit "Login", :disable_with => 'Logining...' %>
    <% end -%>
</div>
<div id="registration_section">
    <% form_for @user do |f| -%>
        <%= f.label :email_address, "Email Address" %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.label :password, "Password" %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.submit "Register", :disable_with => 'Logining...' %>
    <% end -%>
</div>
```

I imagine I will need to use :url => something for those forms, but I am unsure how to specify.

Within routes.rb I have yet to specify either Usersor UserSessions as resources (not convinced that this is the best way to do it... but I could be).

I would like, however, the registration and login on the same page and have implemented this by doing the following:

## routes.rb

```
match 'signup' => 'user#new'
match 'login'  => 'user#new'
```

What's the best way to go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your forms you can specificy the url by doing something like this:

```
<% form_for @user_session, :url => { :action => 'create_session' } do |f| -%>
```

Be aware that defining action names like 'create_session' makes for "non-resourceful routes."  I would suggest consulting the Rails guides on [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to help you get a clearer picture on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not make sense to use a separate controller for this? My thought was simply to use a third controller (not sessions or users) like "Static Pages", and then have both actions available in that controller. This would seem to be more in line with Rails conventions, but I am not positive.